# ElasticSearch architecture and hosting

Tags: mongodb, architecture, hosting, elasticsearch

I am looking to use Elastic Search with MongoDB to support our full text search requirements.  I am struggling to find information on the architecture and hosting and would like some help.  I am planning to host ES on premise rather than in the cloud.  We currently have MongoDB running in replica set with three nodes.

1. How many servers are required to run ElasticSearch for high availability?
2. What is the recommended server specification.  Currently my thoughts are 2 x CPU, 4GB RAM, C drive: 40GB , D drive: 40GB
3. How does ES support failover

Thanks

Tariq

Answer (score 4):

> 1. How many servers are required to run ElasticSearch for high availability?

At least 2

> What is the recommended server specification. Currently my thoughts are 2 x CPU, 4GB RAM, C drive: 40GB , D drive: 40GB

It really depends on the amount of data you're indexing, but that amount of RAM and (I'm assuming a decent dual core CPU) should be enough to get you started

> How does ES support failover

you set up a clustering with multiple nodes in such a way that each node has a replica of another

So in a simple example your cluster would consist of two servers, each with one node on them.
You'd set replicas to 1 so that the shards in your node, would have a backup copy stored on the other node and vice versa.

So if a node goes down, elasticsearch will detect the failure and route the requests for that node to its replica on another node, until you fix the problem.

Of course you could make this even more robust by having 4 servers with one node each and 2 replicas, as an example. What you must understand is that elasticsearch will optimize that distribution of replicas and primary shards based on the number of shards you have.

so with the 2 nodes and 1 replica example above, say you added 2 extra servers/nodes (1 node/server is recommended), Elasticsearch would move the replicas off the nodes and to their own node, so that you'd have 2 nodes with 1 primary shard(s) and nothing else then 2 other nodes with 1 copy of those shards (replicas) each.

Answer (score 0):

> How many servers are required to run ElasticSearch for high
>   availability?

I recommend 3 servers with 3 replication factor index. It will be more stable in case of one server goes down, plus it's better for highload, cause of queries can be distributed through cluster.

> What is the recommended server specification. Currently my thoughts
>   are 2 x CPU, 4GB RAM, C drive: 40GB , D drive: 40GB

I strongly recommend more RAM. We have 72Gb on each machine in the cluster and ES works perfectly smooth (and we still never fall in garbage collector issues)

> How does ES support failover

In our case at [http://indexisto.com](http://indexisto.com/) we had a lot of test and some production cluster server fails. Starting from 3 server no any issues in case server goes down. More servers in cluster - less impact of one server fail.